# Bittorrent software files called dlimagecache

Tags: bittorrent

I have Bittorrent and today I was browsing through the program files and came across a folder called dlimagecache and inside of that were files with random names. I wanted to know what information is in this files and can I delete them?

Comment: Quit BT, move the folder elsewhere, run BT and check - does it recreate the folder?

Comment: SWAG: download image cache? Probably where it stores downloaded pieces of files that are either incomplete or have not yet had their checksums verified.

Answer (score 1):

These are just some advertisement images your Bittorrent client has cached.

They are safe to delete but then you might be reading the same ads all over again.